# "alsa/asoundlib.h " is not found in SDK

Tags: embedded-linux, alsa, yocto, bitbake

I am using Freescale community BSP Daisy 1.6.

In my Yocto `build/conf/local.conf`,  I have added `alsa-lib alsa-tools alsa-state alsa-utils alsa-utils-alsaconf fsl-alsa-plugins` as well as `alsa-lib-dev alsa-tools-dev alsa-state-dev alsa-utils-dev` etc...  Also, I have added all the applications in this recipe [hio-image-fb](https://github.com/HIO-Project/meta-hio-demos/blob/master/recipes-hio/images/hio-image-fb.bb)

However, when I use `bitbake -c populate_sdk core-image-full-cmdline`.  The alsa library is not added in there.  I need `alsa/asoundlib.h` and other headers.

I also added `SDKIMAGE_FEATURES = "dev-pkgs dbg-pkgs staticdev-pkgs"` but alsa library is still missing.  I ended up need to get the complete `sysroots` to replace the one generated from the SDK.

Why is the alsa libraries header are missing in the SDK even when it is suppose to generate the SDK based on the image?  Any idea?

Comment: Please show us what you did in `conf/local.conf`. Also, what version of YP / OpenEmbedded are you using and which layers are you using?

Comment: Hello @Anders, I have edited the question, thank you for your help.